# Difference of Microsoft runtimes dotnet-runtime-6.0.13-win-x64.msi and dotnet-runtime-6.0.13-win-x64.exe (they work differently)

Tags: .net, .net-core

I've created a Visual Studio 2022 dummy project with this csproj file

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>dotnet_6_dependency_test</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I've compiled an executable which should be published.
I do **not** want it to be self contained since I have multiple binaries targeting net6.0 and want to provide the runtime once.

On a vanilla machine I cannot run this binary, because net6 runtime is missing. How do I provide it?

On my developer machine the only matching package to provide a dotnet runtime seems to be
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.NetCore.SharedFramework.6.0.6.0.13,version=17.4.33213.308,machinearch=x64\dotnet-runtime-6.0.13-win-x64.msi`

When I run my program on a machine without dotnet6 I get

```
Architecture: x64
App host version: 6.0.13
.NET location: Not found

Learn about runtime installation:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

Download the .NET runtime:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64&apphost_version=6.0.13
```

I thought ok, install `dotnet-runtime-6.0.13-win-x64.msi` then. But this does not work. The runtime package that visual studio provides me with, does not allow me to execute the program that I've build with this Visual Studio.

I had to download and install a totally different looking `dotnet-runtime-6.0.13-win-x64.exe` (Note: This is an **exe** and not an **msi**).

Now I can execute my program without issues.

Can somebody explain to me what the difference between msi and exe for those runtimes is supposed to be? The MSI packages appears to be useful and its details say:

> This installer database contains the logic and data required to install Microsoft .NET Runtime - 6.0.13 (x64).

except that it does not really work.

My goal is to provide the dotnet runtime along with multiple *non* self-contained binaries without downloading dependencies from the internet.

Currently it appears that I cannot do this because my development machine has no prerequisites available (although it appears it has) to provide a working non self-contained binary alongside with the runtime. I have to go to Microsoft and search for the runtime dependency on the web.